How to overwrite font used on Jekyll site
I set up my site using the hack.css template. In my head it seems like it fetches the stylesheet using
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/hack/dist/hack.css" />
  {% if site.theme_mode == 'standard' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/hack/dist/standard.css" />
  {% elsif site.theme_mode == 'dark' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/hack/dist/dark.css" />
  {% endif %}

I adapted it quite a lot to match my needs (see the repository here). However, I am desperatly trying to overwrite / change the font used on my site (i.e. the stylesheet).
I tried making changes to the main.scss and the _style.csss. Thing is: I cannot even find any mention of (for example):
body {   
...   
font: 18px/1.4 $helvetica; 
} 

Ultimately, I would like to change the font of the entire site to Helvetica (or any googlefont really).
Thank you for helping out!

Have you tried adding body { font : 14pt Helvetica } to one of your CSS files?
